# Preparing to recycle

Tags: windows

When I click "cancel" while it saying "preparing to recycle", does it delete the file? Because I saw green moving bars.  I accidentally clicked "delete" on `System32` and I am scared I will lose some of the files and might have problems with my computer. If I try to delete it, is it actually removed?

Answer (score 2):

If you clicked 'cancel' while it was preparing to recycle, then it should have stopped the process, and even if you tried to recycle/delete the System32 folder, you shouldn't be able to, unless you fiddled around with the User Account Control settings or Command Prompt to do that, which isn't easy, and even then some of the files are still in use which means you can't delete them. So, basically, if your computer is still working, don't worry about it.